# File already exists

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro that distributes a group of files into various subfolders. However, I'm getting a "file already exists" error when trying to move the file. It occurs on the 2nd and 3rd oFSO.movefile statements. Any Ideas? I tried adding a "\" to the end of the filename but then it gives me a type mismatch error?

PS. please bear with me, I don't have any formal training in VBA.

thanks!

```
Sub DistributeDD()
MsgBox ("To use this Macro, Place all loan numbers you want to create     folders for in column A starting at A1 and the sponsor in column B or C")
SourceFolder = InputBox("Paste the Path where the files are located")
Dim oFSO
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim NewFolder As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim TestString As String
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim subfolder As String
Dim Sponsor As String
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)

For i = 1 To LastRow
LoanID = Cells(i, 1).Value
Sponsor = Cells(i, 2).Value
Sponsor2 = Cells(i, 3).Value

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        TestString = oFile.Name
        'Populate Collateral File
        If InStr(UCase(TestString), UCase(LoanID)) > 0 Then
            NewFolder = LoanID
            subfolder = IdentifySubfolder(TestString)
        createNewDirectory (SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder)
        createNewDirectory (SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder & "\" & subfolder)
        oFSO.movefile Source:=oFile, Destination:=SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder & "\" & subfolder & "\"
        End If
        'Populate Sponsor
        If InStr(UCase(TestString), UCase(Sponsor)) > 0 Then
            NewFolder = LoanID
            subfolder = IdentifySubfolder(TestString)
        createNewDirectory (SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder)
        createNewDirectory (SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder & "\" & Sponsor)
        oFSO.movefile Source:=oFile, Destination:=SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder & "\" & Sponsor
        MsgBox (TestString)
        End If
        'Populate Sponsor2
        If InStr(UCase(TestString), UCase(Sponsor)) > 0 Then
            NewFolder = LoanID
            subfolder = IdentifySubfolder(TestString)
        createNewDirectory (SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder)
        createNewDirectory (SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder & "\" & Sponsor2)
        createNewDirectory (SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder & "\" & Sponsor2 & "\" & subfolder)
        oFSO.movefile Source:=oFile, Destination:=SourceFolder & "\" & NewFolder & "\" & Sponsor2
        End If

Next oFile
Next i

Set oFolder = Nothing
Set oFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not 100% positive on this one, but perhaps stick a final `& "\"` on the end of those last two `oFSO.movefile` calls.

Comment: Each `If` block has `NewFolder = LoanID`, but shouldn't the 2nd and 3rd instance use something like `Sponsor` and `Sponsor2` ?

Comment: Thank you, I did add the final & "\" on the other two. this was necessary but not what was causing my error. I removed the redundant code reassigning newfolder to loanid since it only needs to be assigned at the top. I do want it to populate the sponsor and sponsor2 folders within the loanID folder.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that columns Sponsor (2) and Sponsor2 (3) have the same information? If so, the folder created under the SourceFolder\NewFolder will have the same name.

Also, I don't know why you're testing those columns with the file's name, but at line 42 you're testing with 'Sponsor' again.

```
If InStr(UCase(TestString), UCase(Sponsor)) > 0 Then
```

Depending on your data, it might be the source of the problem.

Comment: good catch! I had missed this bug. Strangely it seems that my problem lies in the third if statement. When that field is blank (or even contains a 0) then the if statement for some reason returns true and the code continues to go through it. When I change it to a word the if statement correctly returns false... very strange but it seems to be working now.

Comment: According to the official specificiation, that is how the InStr function works.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx

Could you post your code for future reference?